# Notifications of replies to posts in SourceForge.net

Tags: notifications, forums

I'm using a SourceForge.net forum and I was wondering if I can subscribe to my posts in order to get email notifications when someone replies.

I'm currently using "Monitoring" functionality, but it seems to work only at forum level and not at post level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the forums, when viewing the topics, you should see a column on the right for monitoring options.

Click on the orange RSS icon to grab the feed of that topic.

[image: rss icon in the options column]

You can just use your RSS reader of choice to get notice of replies.

Or you can use some RSS-to-email service (e.g., Feed My Inbox, Feed Mailer, etc.) to have those RSS items sent to your inbox.